rpc service provider
I am new to Solana(EVM specialized)
I looking for a decent rpc provider, specially one that doesn't charges requests for every event in log subscription, as solana does not support filters.
Any ethereum rpc provider will only charge for a subscription connection, but not every single log we receive. My question, does anyone know a solana rpc provider that does this?
Also, I am considering running my own rpc node, I would need access to all historical data up until a specific block, is it possible to configure a full node or to only hold partial data or a rpc node to hold more then normally?
Any help is welcome.
